# EF many to many strange behaviour

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

Only problems with EF many to many :(
Everything worked with my model but I couldn't perform CRUD with many to many entities until  I added this line of code

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Advert>()
                   .HasMany(a => a.WhoAmILookingForTags)
                   .WithMany(a => a.Adverts)
                   .Map(at =>
                   {
                       at.ToTable("AdvertTags");
                       at.MapLeftKey("AdvertId");
                       at.MapRightKey("TagId");
                   });
```

Advert is also connected to Competition and User

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Advert>().HasRequired(u => u.User);
 modelBuilder.Entity<Advert>().HasRequired(c => c.Competition);
```

When I open ServerExplorer and view TableData for Advert I see that there is connection between Advert and User and Competition (fields CompetitionId and UserId are not empty)
And table AdvertTags contains keys for Adverts and Tags
But when in View I try to show model.user.name (model being advert) field is empty (same for tags and for competition)

For example when in controller I do this:

```
Advert advert = db.Adverts.Find(id);

        if (advert == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
```

and in in View I do model => model.User.Name and run application nothing is shown in field User Name.

But when I iterate to all adverts and write smth. like this.

```
database.Adverts.Include(a => a.User).Include.(a => a.Competition)
           .Include(a => a.WhoWhoAmILookingForTags)
```

Everything is shown fine.

I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Do you use `Include` when you load the `Advert` for the view (controller GET action)?

Comment: Nop, the strange thing is that everything worked fine before .Map ...

Comment: Are the navigation properties `WhoAmILookingForTags`, `User` and `Competition` marked as `virtual` in your `Advert` class (necessary for lazy loading)? Anyway, even if lazy loading would work I would prefer the `Include`s in the controller action because it's only a single database query.

Comment: Please can you tell me how can I use Include when I want only one advert ?

Comment: `SingleOrDefault` instead of `Find`: `Advert advert = db.Adverts.Include(...).SingleOrDefault(a => a.AdvertId == id)`.

Comment: Thanks it works now =) do you maybe know why this happened after adding .Map ?

Comment: No, I don't know. Adding the Fluent mapping shouldn't have any effect on this.